# put a placeholder in nested parens when using cut

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme

`cut` macro is defined in [SRFI-26](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-26/srfi-26.html).

Using this macro, you can write:

```
(cut + 3 <>)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
(lambda (x) (+ 3 x))
```

However, when putting `<>` inside the the child parens, it won't work.

```
(cut + 3 (* 2 <>))
```

Chicken Scheme interpreter terminates with the following error when we try to apply it.

> Error: bad argument count - received 1 but expected 0: #<procedure (?)>

I wan't it to be equivalent to:

```
(lambda (x) (+ 3 (* 2 x)))
```

Is there any syntax sugar that I can shorten the above code in Chicken Scheme?

Comment: This might be the egg you need? http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/holes

Comment: @soegaard Thanks! Using the `holes` egg, I can write `##( + 3 (* 2 !!))` . please post it as answer and I will accept it.